# how to add el-input&el-select in el-table?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, element-plus

my el-table title(many cols) was get form the database. How to add el-input & el-select in the table?

```
        <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
            <el-table-column v-for="col in partstitle" :key="col.id" :label="col.title">
            </el-table-column>
        </el-table>
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?
Or were you looking for the solution given in answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Table with custom header](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#table-with-custom-header) to put your controls in the table header and [Custom column template](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#custom-column-template) to change the column content.

```
<el-table-column label="Input">
    <template #header>
        <el-input v-model="search" size="mini" placeholder="Type to search" />
    </template>
</el-table-column>

<el-table-column label="Select">
    <template #default="scope">
        <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select">
        ...
        </el-select>          
    </template> 
</el-table-column>
```